# Hide value in Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Typeahead with PHP to display a list from a database using source.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
require( "config.php" );
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

$query = $_POST['query'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%{$query}%'";
$array = array();

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    $array[] = $row['title'] . ',' . $row['id'];
}

// Return the json array
echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

You can see that I add both 'title' and 'id' to the array. All I want it to display in the typeahead is the title but I need the id for the links. Here is the JS:

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "source.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'query=' + query,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data){
            process(data);
        }
    })
},
sorter: function (items) {
items.unshift(this.query); // Includes a new row with exact search query
return items.sort();
},
        updater: function (item) {
            document.location = "/companies/" + item.replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/\,/g,'/').toLowerCase() + "/";
            return item;
        }
});
```

In the line beginning document.location I replace the comma between the two values with a forward slash and it works e.g. /england/123/. But it's the typeahead display that shows it as England,123 rather than just England.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not the exact answer to your question but this might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389948/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-id-label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK managed to get a result with the following:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
require( "config.php" );
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

$query = $_POST['query'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%{$query}%'";
$array = array();

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    $array[] = array('label' => $row['title'], 'id' =>$row['id']);
}

// Return the json array
echo json_encode($array);
}
```

JS:

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.stubowker.com/amex/cms/source.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'query=' + query,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data){
objects = [];
    map = {};
    $.each(data, function(i, object) {
        map[object.label] = object;
        objects.push(object.label);
    });
    process(objects);
        }
    })
},
sorter: function (items) {
items.unshift(this.query); // Includes a new row with exact search query
return items.sort();
},
    updater: function (item) {
        document.location = "/companies/" + map[item].label.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase() + "/" + map[item].id + 

"/";
        return item;
    }
});
```