# Typeahead.js not showing custom template for prefetched data

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm using twitter's `typeahead.js` to show an autocomplete.

My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/getlocals/',
    success: function(data){
        $('.local-type').typeahead({
            name: 'local-tt',
            source: data,
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{locality}}</strong> – {{city}}</p>')
        })
    }
});
```

Where data is a json response from `/getlocals/` and has the following format:

```
[{
"locality": "Powai",
"city": "Mumbai",
}, {
"locality": "Colaba",
"city": "Mumbai",
}, {
"locality": "Andheri East",
"city": "Mumbai",
}, {
"locality": "Andheri West",
"city": "Mumbai",
}]
```

This however doesn't work and I have a feeling that the `source` option is not receiving the correct format. What sort of format is `typeahead` looking for and how do I provide it?

EDIT:

I've also used part of the solution provided here: [Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead - Id & Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389948/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-id-label/13277173#13277173) but this doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: @Daedalus Sorry, that was me writing the structure without copying it from the response. I've edited it.

Comment: Thanks; comment deleted since it is now outdated.

Comment: @Daedalus Sure. Any suggestions  to fix this? I'm using Django to send the `data` variable if that makes any difference.

Comment: Currently debugging your problem in a re-created environment.

Comment: Tried `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @guest271314 The ajax call returns the correct data if that's what you mean. I can see it in the network tab.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253261/create-customize-type-head-using-jquery-and-bootstrap-typeahead/

Comment: @guest271314 That worked. I don't know why or how. But that worked. Thank you!!

Comment: I should have paid attention to the comments, then I wouldn't have put time into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, reading the [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets), you did a few things wrong with this plugin;

First, your plugin usage is incorrect; options are specified in one object, and data-sets in another:

```
$('.local-type').typeahead({/*options*/}, {/*data set1*/}, {/*optional data set 2*/});
```

In the case of your example, it'd be something like this:

```
$('.local-type').typeahead({
    name: 'local-tt',
}, {
    source: function (query, cb) {
        cb(data);
    },
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{locality}}</strong> – {{city}}</p>')
    }
});
```

To explain the above, the 'suggestion' key is a child of the 'templates' key, it does not exist stand-alone.  The 'source' key is a function, not an array.  The function is passed the query, and the 'callback' function, which is then executed with the data as the parameter.

Secondly, your method of creating an instance of the typeahead plugin, within an ajax call, is not preferred assuming that ajax call is executed more than one time.  If it is not, then disregard the following suggestion, which is to put the ajax call -within- the typeahead plugin creation, as such:

```
$('.local-type').typeahead({
    name: 'local-tt',
}, {
    source: function (query, cb) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/getlocals/',
            success: function(data){
                cb(data);
            }
        });
    },
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
            '</div>'].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{locality}}</strong> – {{city}}</p>')
    }
});
```

This is of course assuming the ajax request is made more than once; if it is not, disregard the above.

[**Basic demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/d69dk9wn/)

Comment: Thank you! I prefer this solution to the one in the comments. You've explained it quite well and now I understand why my code wasn't working. +1